# Modifying SQL query for nhibernate in VS2010 web project

Tags: sql, nhibernate

To preface, I am far from a programmer.  I have unfortunately been tasked with modifying an ASP .NET web-based inout board using SQL as the DB that was created by a former employee of the company I work for.  Despite not being a programmer, my employer still seems to want to throw this on me, so I apologize if I'm too vague.

Basically, I need to modify the SQL query in the following function to grab the second smallest value from the "rsRank" column instead of the smallest (basically the second highest ranked employee with a stauts of "In", rather than the highest ranked as it currently is).  I'm able to build an SQL query in SQL management studio with no issues to get the value I need, but can't figure out how to implement it into the below code.  I know next to nothing about nhibernate/HQL and how the mappings, etc, work.

```
    public Employee GetCurrentDesignatedRS()
    {
        using (ISession session = _nhHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var employee = session.CreateQuery("from Employee emp1 where emp1.rsRank = (select min(emp2.rsRank) from Employee emp2 where emp2.Status = 'In' and emp2.rsRank > 0)").UniqueResult<Employee>();
            return employee;
        }
    }
```

Below is the SQL query I made that gets me the value I need:

```
    select top 1 emp2.rsRank from Employee emp2 where emp2.rsRank > (select min(emp2.rsRank) from Employee emp2) and emp2.Status='In'
```

Of course, if I simply plug this in place of the existing query, I get the following exception:

```
    Message: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 87 [from CompanyName.InOut.Library.Entities.Employee emp1 where emp1.rsRank = (select top 1 emp2.rsRank from CompanyName.InOut.Library.Entities.Employee emp2 where emp2.rsRank > (select min(emp2.rsRank) from CompanyName.InOut.Library.Entities.Employee emp2) and emp2.Status='In')]
```

I figure this is a long shot, but if someone could at least point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: I understand that it is frustrating to be tasked with something that's beyond your qualifications and interests. Unfortunately, this makes your question a bad fit for this site, where users are expected to more or less understand and research the problem on their own first, and write in a way that makes the question and answers useful for other developers, not just themselves.

Comment: Diego, why not try and help someone out instead of burning them down?

Comment: Diego, it's people with attitudes like yours that make me glad I don't have to frequent places like this often.  To accuse me of not researching when, in fact, I researched for a solid two days, is laughable.  I don't recall holding a gun to your head asking you to help me.  I think I explained my situation well enough that your post is both useless and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (not tested):

```
        var employee = session.CreateQuery(
            "from Employee emp1 where emp1.rsRank > " +
            "(select min(emp2.rsRank) from Employee emp2 where emp2.Status = 'In' and emp2.rsRank > 0) " +
            " order by emp1.rsRank")
            .SetMaxResults(1)
            .UniqueResult<Employee>();
```

Alternatively, if all you need is the rank and not the employee then you can use a SQL query:

```
var rank = session.CreateSQLQuery("select top 1 emp2.rsRank from Employee emp2 where emp2.rsRank > (select min(emp2.rsRank) from Employee emp2) and emp2.Status='In'")
                  .UniqueResult<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Employee GetCurrentDesignatedRS()
    {
        using (ISession session = _nhHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var employee = session.CreateSQLQuery("select top 1 emp2.rsRank from Employee emp2 where emp2.rsRank > (select min(emp2.rsRank) from Employee emp2) and emp2.Status='In'").UniqueResult<Employee>();
            return employee;
        }
    }
```